# Webapp - can you separate out the client side js?

Tags: google-apps-script

The way I've been building my google web apps is with all of the client side js in the html file, and all of the server side code in the code.gs files. Is there any way to separate the JS from the HTML while keeping it inside the project?

Comment: You just need to use printing scriplets they're explained [here[(https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates?hl=en}  and then use a function like this `function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();`
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, take a look at Google's [Separate HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#separate_html_css_and_javascript) guide.

Apps Script only allows for `.gs` and `.html` files, so you have to wrap your JS in `<script></script>` tags and save it in an HTML file.